# Graphing live re-syncing data in D3js in a fixed window with linear easing

Tags: d3.js

I'm interested in graphing live-ish data in D3js.  Now, when I say "live-ish" I mean that I'll be collecting data every 200ms +/- 10ms, but there may be several minute long periods of inactivity.  Fortunately, the input data is time-stamped!

What I have so far:  I've followed some line drawing in d3 guides (eg: [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/)) and I have a Y axis with the value range/domain I want.  I have an X axis with the range I want and a moving domain as per a standard time-series fixed-width graph.  That is, if my graph's x axis domain is (0:15, 0:35) in 5 seconds it will be (0:20, 0:40).  This transitions nicely as it's using linear easing.

I have mock-data being output each iteration of the graph tick.  My domain is set up as such that new points are just out of the x-axis domain such as to allow the smooth effect as per [1](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/). All in all, it looks great.

So where do I go from here? My desired result: data comes in asynchronously and is placed precisely at its x-axis time-stamped location.  If data is up to date, it gets placed juuust outside the x-axis domain and has a smooth transition in.  If data doesn't arrive in time, the graph continues without drawing any new points until data is received, at which time it adds each point at its appropriate time-stamp retroactively. If data for the missing period doesn't arrive at all, we just continue with a gap in the graph. I can emulate this by calling...

```
d3.select(window).on("click", .. )
```

Effectively, I can click to add random data at the current time-stamp using some anonymous function which allows me to mimic the data / event structure my code should handle.

I think my current confusion is due to how I add data and draw the path from it.

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
  .interpolate("basis-open")
  .x(function(d, i) { return x(now - (n-1-i)*duration); })
  .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

var axis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(x.axis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

var path = svg.append("g")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  .append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
```

The big question: my y-values correspond to the path.datum(data) (data is just an array of values) appropriately, but when I push to the data array to draw the line, it always places each point graphically at equal distance apart.  How do I break out of the mono-variable graph without destroying my time-series smooth scrolling animation?  I could record a second array of timestamps alongside my data array, but how to I integrate those into the line? Ideally, I'd have them both be a part of the same array so I could sort by timestamp so when I call data.shift() truly the oldest data is gone.  I tried changing the "duration" of the transition function but it made the graph accelerate weirdly and didn't actually break the equidistance of points on x.

How do I set up the y-axis graph to also take into account x-location without breaking my graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out a pretty straightforward way of doing exactly what I wanted while still using .datum(data) instead of .data(data) (where 'data' is my array).  Instead of passing in an array of values to .datum, I pass in an array of objects.  Or, what was once data = [value1, value2, ...] is now data = [{gx:timestamp1, gy:value1}, {gx:timestamp2, gy:value2}, ...].

My line x-axis / y-axis functions are now...

```
.x(function(d, i) { return x(d.gx); })
.y(function(d, i) { return y(d.gy); });
```

Which ends up being a bit neater than my initial run at it.  My transition functions didn't have to change.

The final puzzle piece was what to do about data that comes in time-stamped but out of order.  Fortunately, my display domain isn't very large and thus, I don't need to store many values in the array.  As such, when new data comes in I simply sort it to make the line not a wobbly-bobbly mess.

```
data.sort(function(a,b){ return a.gx - b.gx});
```

And voila!  If the size of the array is beyond the boundary, shift off data.  This gives us the effect of a sliding timeseries window of the past n seconds where time-stamped data points may be arbitrarily dumped on and displayed properly.